# What methods are called after a FragmentTransaction

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, adapter, fragmenttransaction

After a Transaction is made in a `FragmentActivity`, will the Fragment's `onActivityCreated()` be called?

I populate a `ListView` in `onActivityCreated()` with an `adapter`. I'm hoping the Transaction is another way that will update the list and adapter if needed. Even if that Fragment is already in view and the parent  `Activity` calls a Transaction to the same one.

Or is `onCreateView()` more suitable?

Comment: Have you read the Doc about the Fragment Lifecycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the Transaction as a method to update, why on earth would you do that?

That's akin to saying, I'm going to use onDraw in a view as a way to count seconds.

onActivityCreated will only be called when the activity is being created (onCreate()) so unless you destroy the activity, it won't happen.

Hint: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Hey thanks... that answers what I needed.  I guess you're right.  I was doing something kind of a hackish way so I will try to do it properly.

Comment: :) Glad it helped you. If you need to update fragments, use an observer/listener pattern and notify the interested parties about any event (using an Interface) :)